# Dimension of $\text{Hom}(U,V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I read this question and do not understand: [Dimension of Hom(U, V)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26592/dimension-of-homu-v?rq=1)

However, my question is more primitive - so regardless the complex discussion related to the two paper in the question and accepted answer, is the dimension of $\text{Hom}(U,V)$ just dim$U \times$ dim$V$?

Thanks!

Comment: If these are just finite dimensional vector spaces over $k$ then choosing bases kicks off a chain of isomorphisms $\operatorname{Hom}(U, V) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(k^n, k^m) \cong \operatorname{Mat}_{m \times n}(k) \cong k^{mn}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field. If $U$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb K$ with basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1,\dots,n}$ and $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb K$ with basis $\{w_j\}_{j=1,\dots,m}$, then  $\{\varphi_{ij}\}$ with

$$\varphi_{ij}(e_k)=\delta_{ik}w_j$$

is a basis for $Hom(U,V)$ with cardinality $nm$.

Comment: Very clear, thank you!

Comment: you are welcome